# Super Global SERVER Variable alternative in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.0, coding-standards, magento-ecg

I am creating extension in Magento2 and also try to follow the all coding standards that magento2 is recommending using EcgM2 standard. Can any one tell me alternative of **SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** variable. What i have done is below. I am using SERVER variable alternative in Helper so following is my construct and i have add dependency of $httpRequest

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $httpRequest,\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this -> scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this -> storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this -> logger = $logger;
        // MY CUSTOM Request Property 
        $this-> request = $httpRequest;
    }
```

Further i have used it like below

```
 $domain =$this->request->getServer('SERVER_NAME');
```

Is it correct ? Is it better idea?

Can anyone have reference link of documentation that shows the alternative of these global variable and not allowed function in magento2 like

> $FILE,base64_decode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok! I got solution for one or two global variable. I will update question if i found more.

For **$_SERVER**

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $httpRequest,\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this -> scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this -> storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this -> logger = $logger;
        // MY CUSTOM Request Property 
        $this-> request = $httpRequest;
    }
```

Step1: I have added **$httpRequest** to my __construct and assign to $this_request

Step2: Later we can use that variable like

```
 $domain =$this->request->getServer('SERVER_NAME');
```

For **$_FILE**

```
public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory) {
        $this -> _filesystem = $filesystem;
        // It is required 
        $this -> _fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;

    }
```

Step1: I have added **$fileUploaderFactory** to my __construct and assign to $this -> _fileUploaderFactory

Step2: Later we can use that variable like

```
$uploader = $this -> _fileUploaderFactory -> create(['fileId' => $this -> getAttribute() -> getName()]);
```

I am using above code in my Model under afterSave method